# How to configure Case Sensitive Paths in Apache Camel in Spring Boot or Quarkus?

Tags: rest, apache-camel, quarkus, case-sensitive, spring-camel

Currently I'm integrating some projects in Quarkus and Spring Boot, both of them using Apache Camel to raise up a Rest API, but I'm facing a rare problem. In Spring Boot the requests seems not to be case sensitive, but in Quarkus they are, so how can I configure case sensitive in any of them?
I'm testing with the following code

```
public class RestService extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
            .port("8080")
            .apiProperty("cors","true");

    rest("/say")
            .get("/hello").to("direct:hello");

    from("direct:hello").routeId("hello")
            .log("Request arrived")
            .transform().constant("Hello world from Spring Boot");


     }
}
```

I've tried to set matchOnUriPrefix in true and false, but that doesn't seem to affect anything

Comment: It likely depends on which component you are using for the REST DSL.

E.g for `camel-servlet`, REST path matching is done in a case insensitive way. On Quarkus, the `platform-http` compoment is used by default as the HTTP consumer for the REST DSL. It is backed by Vert.x and path matching is case sensitive.

If you want identical behavior between Spring Boot and Quarkus, then try to use the same component for the REST DSL.

Comment: Thanks @JamesNetherton, that solves the problem, adding `camel-servlet` to dependencies and using `.component("servlet")` in `.restConfiguration()` in Quarkus seems to behave identically to Spring Boot.